# what does "The investment we brought up to have" mean

Tags: complex-sentences

I am translating a book called Missing Out (https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Missing_Out/6sgL6iqrHZUC?hl=en&gbpv=0)

the book is about psychoanalysis and philosophy which is written not in direct and fluent language. in one of the sentences you can read:

> Getting it, or not getting it - both the experience, which is acute,
> and the phrase, which seems not to be - reminds us of the investment
> we are brought up to have in understanding as a measure of intimacy
> and competence;

what does "the investment we brought up to have" mean?  can someone rewrite it in a simpler form? is this a correct understanding: we are brought up in a way to have an investment in understanding ...

Comment: Yes, that's about it. We think we should all be "getting it." See if "intimace" is supposed to be *intimacy*.

Comment: Please transcribe accurately.

Comment: "What does 'the investment we **are** brought up to have' mean?" If you want this post to proper, please take some time to transcribe the text more carefully as well as form the question grammatically. ("what means"...and _intimace_)?

Comment: I think there was an earlier quotation by this author. These tortured sentences perhaps reflect the quality of his thinking.

Comment: @Xanne [This is the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Phillips_(psychologist)).

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, I knew that. On a scale of torturing the language, he gets 9 out of 10.

Comment: it was just two typos and I have fixed it. Why you are complaining about the way the author is writing; some authors write more complicated than the others.

Comment: It means that whoever wrote that was incapable of writing clear English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reminds us of the investment we are brought up to have in
> understanding as a measure of intimacy and competence;

*appears* to mean that, during our upbringing, we are subconsciously taught to use "understanding" both as a way to judge intimacy and as a way to gauge competence.